# CPU Pipe Underrun Errors

Tags: boot, kali-linux, cpu

Every time upon booting and then unlocking my GUI session on Kali Linux 2.0, I get another of this error in Virtual Console 1:

```
[ 1235.586792] [drm:intel_set_cpu_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared fifo underrun on pipe A
[ 1235.586827] [drm:ironlake_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
```

What does this error mean? Is it any significant thing to worry about?